# Error "Unable to load asset" al cargar una imagen en una aplicación de Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Al momento de ejecutar mi aplicación, me manda una *Excepción* la cual me dice lo siguiente:

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/backgrounds/login_consumidores.png

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load 
package:flutter/…/services/asset_bundle.dart:221
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync 
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:464
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load 
package:flutter/…/painting/image_provider.dart:449
...
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/backgrounds/login_consumidores.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#215d5(), name: "assets/backgrounds/login_consumidores.png", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Esto pasa cuando quiero mostrar una imagen en la misma aplicación con el siguiente código:

```dart
Widget _imagenFondo(){
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/backgrounds/login_consumidores.png'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
```

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente:

[image: Estructura de los archivos del proyecto]

Y pues por último, investigando en internet encontré que puede ser por problemas del pubspec.yaml, pero según yo lo tengo correcto:

```
flutter:

  uses-material-design: true


  assets:
    - assets/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falto poner la referencia a la carpeta `backgrounds`, al poner el directorio , solo reconoce los assets/archivos que estén dentro de este, mas no subdirectorios.

```
  assets:
    - assets/backgrounds/
```

Comment: Sólo para añadir también es necesario poner el "/" del final, Gracias.