# Añadir imagen en un menuDrawer , error "Unable to load asset"

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Estoy intentando añadir una imagen a un menuDrawer pero al parecer  la imagen no tiene las medidas necesaria  y no es capaz de mostrar imagen. El objetivo es que llegue a cargar la imagen en la parte superior del menuDrawer.

Adjunto mensaje de error

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: images/fondo.png
```

Adjunto código

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          // color: Colors.blue,
          image: AssetImage(
              'images/fondo.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      
      ),
```

Comment: hola, antes de crear una nueva pregunta, por favor actualizar las preguntas que ya fueron respondidas : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/520881/a%c3%b1adir-bot%c3%b3n-de-barra-de-navegaci%c3%b3n-en-flutter

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Error al cargar una imagen en una aplicacion de flutter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/307320/error-al-cargar-una-imagen-en-una-aplicacion-de-flutter)

Comment: @diegoveloper , Si ya esta solucionado.Gracias

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error:

> Unable to load asset: images/fondo.png

Asegura que en tu proyecto exista la imagen `fondo.png` dentro del directorio `images/` que se encontraría en la raíz de tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en tu archivo `pubspec.yaml` asegura que este definido el directorio que contiene la imagen:

```
  assets:
      - images/
```